# applying sapply to loop over the numeric indices

Tags: r, loops, sapply

I have a matrix named rainfal (315576 by 19 matrix). I would like to transform each column of this matrix to a matrix with 24 columns so that I can have 19 24-column matrices. I have tried this codes and but still have problem to get the desired results.

```
sapply(seq_along(rainfal), function(i) {
    matrix(rainfal[, i], nrow(rainfal)/24, 24, byrow=TRUE)
})
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each the matrices in a `list`

```
res <-  lapply(seq_len(ncol(rainfall)), function(i) 
                   matrix(rainfall[,i], ncol=24, byrow=TRUE) )

sapply(res, dim)
#   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#[1,] 13149 13149 13149 13149 13149 13149 13149 13149 13149 13149 13149 13149
#[2,]    24    24    24    24    24    24    24    24    24    24    24    24
#   [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19]
#[1,] 13149 13149 13149 13149 13149 13149 13149
#[2,]    24    24    24    24    24    24    24
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 rainfall <- matrix(sample(1:20, 315576*19, replace=TRUE), ncol=19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, using the properties of matrices in R:

```
M <- matrix(1:(19*315576) ,nc=19)   # 315576 rows, 19 columns; just an example
dim(M) <- c(315576/24,24,19)
```

So this takes a 2-dimensional matrix `M` with 315,576 rows and 19 columns, and "re-dimensions" it to a 3-dimensional matrix; essentially 19 matrices each with 315576 / 24 rows and 24 columns. Then, if you prefer the 19 matrices in a list, you can do this:

```
lst <- lapply(1:19,function(i)M[,,i])
```